# Showing the order of growth of the function

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, time-complexity

I have the following code

```
int sum = 0; 
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i = i*2) 
{ 
   for (int j = 1; j <=n; ++j) 
   { 
       ++sum;
    }
}
```

And I have the following analysis which according to some people is wrong even though the answer is correct, but I don't understand why.

So, I do the following,

```
n = 1; i = 1; j is being executed 1 time  
n = 2; i = 2; j is being executed 2* 1 time  
n = 3; i = 4; j = 4 * 3 times  
n = 4; i = 8; j = 8 * 4 times  
n = 5; i = 16; j = 16 * 5 times  
......  
n = k; i = 2^k; j = n * 2^k times
```

And since 2^k  is log(n)

The order of growth of this function is nlog(n) which is a linearithmic growth rate.

Am I doing something wrong in my analysis? Please let me know if I have any mistakes because it is confusing me a lot. Thank you! I want to apply this analysis to more complicated nested loops, but before I do that I need to know what I'm doing wrong.

Update: I spent a lot of time by myself trying to figure out why my analysis is wrong. Thanks to @YvesDaoust I think I'm starting to understand it a little bit more.

Comment: Don't post a massive picture of code. Post the code as text.

Comment: The outer loop is `log n` and the inner loop is `n`

Comment: @PeterLawrey I understand that the outer loop is is logn and the inner loop is n, but I'm just trying to create an analysis so that I can apply it to more complicated nested loops.

Comment: And could someone please explain me why I already have -2 down votes? I'm looking for help, and I did my best at editing the post. What is the problem? Stackoverflow users will down vote anything they see?

Comment: @Student that's what I meant, often you can analyses and recognise certain types of loop and multiply them together.

Comment: @PeterLawrey But you cannot always just multiply them, sometimes it could be more difficult and some inner loops will be dependent on the values of the outer for loops like "j" will be dependent on the value "i". In this  case, you cannot just "multiply them together".

Comment: The inner loop is alway executed `n` times but this does not appear in your analysis. Your answer is right by chance.

Comment: I agree with you, the downvotes aren't deserved. You have the right to be wrong :)

Comment: @Student sometimes you can't but in simple cases like this you can.

Comment: @YvesDaoust it is getting ridicilous, i already have 3 down votes and no one is willing to explain why...

Comment: @Student: I don't thank you for not caring about my explanation. My -1 now.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I'm sorry, I thought I explained that in my update. and in my post i was incrementing n each time be one time, so I'm not too sure what your answer is. But I'm really sorry that I did not reply to your answer, I'm new in stackoverflow and I thought you would see my update.

Comment: @Student: you never modify `n`.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thank you, I'm starting to understand it a little more. I guess I cannot use my analysis like that because as you said the inner loop is executed n times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body of the inner loop is executed `n` times.

The body of the outer loop is executed for all powers of 2 from 1 to n and there are about log2(n) of them, hence the global complexity

```
O(n.log(n))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! I really appreciate it.